# Error registering PhantomJS node in Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid, ghostdriver

I have the following problem

- I successfully launched Selenium Grid hub with:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub`

- After that I tried to launch PhantomJS node with:

`phantomjs --webdriver=8090 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444`

---

but got Error:

> [INFO  - 2016-03-25T13:56:28.397Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on
>   port 8090 [INFO  - 2016-03-25T13:56:28.397Z] GhostDriver - Main -
>   registering to Selenium HUB 'http://localhost:4444' version:  using
>   '127.0.0.1:8090' with
>   org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy as remote proxy.
>   [ERROR - 2016-03-25T13:56:28.400Z] GhostDriver - main.fail -
>   {"line":97,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://platform/hub_register.js","stack":"register@phantomjs://platform/hub_register.js:97:79\nglobal
>   code@phantomjs://code/main.js:78:37"}
>
> phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error

Standard node works ok, but PhantomJS failes. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking, there are linux and windows x64 builds available here with the workaround of v2.1.1 (windows build is on a pull request - the hex editor workaround wont work for windows cos the .exe's are compressed)

https://github.com/mrorgues/PhantomJSCustomEdition

Answer (score 5):

workaround***
d/l source from phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/build.html and edit hub_register.js in the src/ghostdriver
comment out lines as shown below:

//var ghostdriver = ghostdriver || {};

```
return {
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: "phantomjs",
        version: version,
        //platform: ghostdriver.system.os.name + '-' + ghostdriver.system.os.version + '-' + ghostdriver.system.os.architecture,
        maxInstances: 1,
        seleniumProtocol: "WebDriver"
```

compile and everything works!

shortcut:
https://github.com/darwin10/phantomjs

Original Source : https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/394

Comment: Thank you very much)
    
    Downloaded .zip from [here]: https://github.com/darwin10/phantomjs
    Launched 'build.sh'
    Launched PhantomJS node
    
    Everything works fine for me)
    
    One thing - I don't know if it is stable enough (phantom version is 2.0.1-development), but it's quite another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing *localhost* with local IP

`phantomjs --webdriver=8090 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444`

with

`phantomjs --webdriver=8090 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444`

Answer (score 1):

You can override part of binary file with the `dd` command.
I'm going to replace `platform:` with `//atform:`:

```
$ cp /usr/local/bin/phantomjs .

$ ./phantomjs --version
2.1.1

$ xxd -c 16 phantomjs | grep -C 2 'platform:'
01c6aaa0: 7273 696f 6e3a 2076 6572 7369 6f6e 2c0a  rsion: version,.
01c6aab0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
01c6aac0: 706c 6174 666f 726d 3a20 6768 6f73 7464  platform: ghostd
01c6aad0: 7269 7665 722e 7379 7374 656d 2e6f 732e  river.system.os.
01c6aae0: 6e61 6d65 202b 2027 2d27 202b 2067 686f  name + '-' + gho

$ printf '//' | dd of=phantomjs conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$((0x01c6aac0+0))
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
2 bytes transferred in 0.000117 secs (17085 bytes/sec)

$ xxd phantomjs | grep 'atform:'
01c6aac0: 2f2f 6174 666f 726d 3a20 6768 6f73 7464  //atform: ghostd

$ ./phantomjs --version
2.1.1

$ mv phantomjs /usr/local/bin/
```

If you cannot locate the string, try to increase octets per line (`xxd -c 256`).

Answer (score 1):

I have spent 2 months trying to fix this problem, trying everything possible, my main issue was that many solutions won't connect to the grid, and ones that do are in docker containers what can only connect to a local grid hosted on the same Docker host.

So... I finally built my own solution which works:
https://github.com/madhavajay/selenium-node-phantomjs

Docker image is madhavajay/selenium-node-phantomjs

It uses PhantomJS 2.1.1 Custom Build with fixed Ghostdriver and then my own tweaks to the latest fork of Ghostdriver to allow a custom --remoteHost param all wrapped up in a Docker Container with configurable Environment Variables.

I hope this saves someone the lost weeks I suffered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Instead of downloading the source code and compiling, as suggested by Ojen G., I used a [fix posted by neuro-sys](https://gist.github.com/neuro-sys/41e368839a9b20dafb34) to make the change in the executable. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Download replacestrings.c program.

   ```
   wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/neuro-sys/3bf00b6cf28a93e07e44/raw/52f715fd49fbd271a9450b61d5cd3cf29907a5a0/replacestring.c
   ```
2. Compile program

   ```
   gcc replacestring.c -o replacestring
   ```
3. Replace Java source code string in binary, creating fixed binary.

   ```
   ./replacestring "$(strings /usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs | grep "platform: ghostdriver")" " " < /usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs > f_phantomjs
   ```
4. Make binary executable; and put as replacement

   ```
   chmod +x f_phantomjs
   sudo chown root:root f_phantomjs
   sudo mv f_phantomjs /usr/lib/phantomjs
   cd /usr/lib/phantomjs
   sudo echo "Fixed error in phantomjs; old file in e_phantomjs" > README.txt
   sudo mv phantomjs e_phantomjs
   sudo ln f_phantomjs phantomjs
   ```

After these steps, it runs fine (Selenium hub already running):

```
phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
[INFO  - 2016-05-07T16:33:35.534Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8080
[INFO  - 2016-05-07T16:33:35.534Z] GhostDriver - Main - registering to Selenium HUB 'http://localhost:4444' version:  using '127.0.0.1:8080' with org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy as remote proxy.
[INFO  - 2016-05-07T16:33:35.604Z] HUB Register - register - Registered with grid hub: http://localhost:4444/ (ok)
```

Comment: the replacestring didn't work, but editing the binary did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Following this gist:
https://gist.github.com/neuro-sys/41e368839a9b20dafb34

Editing the binary to put a `//` in front of the offending line worked for me, but not the string replace thing.

-> Follow the part about using `hdex`

Search for `platform:`

and replace with `//atform:`

by replacing the letters `pl` with `//` (`2F2F` in hex)