# Issue in selenium grid for headless testing using phantom js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using phantomJS for headless testing. I want to execute in 5 headless mode parallelLy. is it possible using selenium grid. I am able to execute parallely in ie, Firefox but how to execute in headless

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run it parallel. but You need to start phantomJS with different port if you are running all phantomJS instances in the same machine. You have to register it to the hub like firefox

Comment: can u edit the below code for phantom js java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\software\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 6987 -browser browserName=iexplore,maxInstances=5

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221498/error-registering-phantomjs-node-in-selenium-grid